# Efficient data structure for Zobrist keys

Tags: c++

Zobrist keys are 64bit hashed values used in board games to univocally represent different positions found during a tree search. They are usually stored in arrays having a size of 1000K entries or more (each entry is about 10 bytes long). The table is usually accessed by `hashKey % size` as index. What kind of STL container would you use to represent this sort of table? Consider that since the size of the table is limited collisions might happen. With a "plain" array I would have to handle this case, so I thought of an unordered_map, but since the implementation is not specified, I am not sure how efficient it will be while the map is being populated.

Comment: Do you need a `map` or would a `set` be sufficient ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me a standard hashmap would suit you well - very fast look up and it will handle the collisions for you reliably and invisibly.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to explore other territories apart STL, take a look at [Judy arrays](http://judy.sourceforge.net/): these should fit your problem.

If you are on Linux you can experiment with them very easily, just install from your repository...

[This](http://judy.sourceforge.net/examples/Judy_hashing.pdf) application note could help to solve your task.

**EDIT**

There is [this](http://judyhash.sourceforge.net/) STL interface: I'm going to experiment with it, then I'll report my results.